# runtime error: signed integer overflow: -1094795586 + -1094795586 cannot be represented in type 'int'

Tags: c, pointers

> Two sum problem.
>
> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
>  */
> ```

This is a beginners problem on Leetcode. The test case is the array `[2,7,11,15]`. It doesn't appear that my code is actually accessing the elements in the array. The variables `nums`, `target`, `numsSize`, and `returnSize` were given. I assumed `numsSize` is the size of the array. when I added a '&' next to `nums` when I set `p= nums`, I just got a stack buffer overflow error.

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */


int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){

    scanf("%d", &numsSize);
    nums = (int*)malloc(numsSize * sizeof(int)); 
    int array[1];
    int* p;
    int* j;

    p = nums;
    int i = 0;

    j = p + 1;

    for(i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){

        if(*p + *j == target){

            array[0] = &p;
            array[1] = &j;

        }

        p++;
        j++;

    }


    return array;

    free(nums);
}
```

expected results by Leetcode.

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

Comment: Well, for starters, `int array[1];` cannot possibly hold two elements, so that's wrong right out of the box. And why you're assigning the address of local *pointers* to array element(s) expecting `int` is equally mysterious. Returning `array` is also wrong, since it expires as soon as the function exists, leaving the caller a worthless address where dereferencing it invokes yet-more undefined behavior. And.. you have a memory leak, since the hard-return will make the `free` call unreachable. Learning to code from sites like "Leet"Code is a *terrible* idea. Get a good book and work through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `array[1] = &j;` is not possible as you are declaring `int array[1]` try `int array[2]` instead of `int array[1]` in line 3 of your code. That should solve the error partially.    Work with arrays as this is the basic concept of array.